# Can I create a single bar beside each stacked bar using zedgraph?

Tags: zedgraph

I currently have some stacked bar graphs created using zedgraph which work very well. The stacked graphs are displaying costs and the stacked bar graph breaks them into different sections. I now want to add a single bar beside each stacked bar to show the available capacity for that stacked bar? Is it possible to do this with Zedgraph?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the [Zedgraph wiki](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index4875.html?title=Main_Page) there is an [example](http://goorman.free.fr/ZedGraph/zedgraph.org/wiki/index9b40.html?title=Percent_Stack_Bar_Demo) with stacked bars and a line curve in the same chart, with the line curve being associated with the Y2 axis. It should be fairly simple to adapt this example, replacing the line curve with single bars.